# Laravel excel import undefined index

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

When I'm trying to import xlsx file I have error:

```
{
    "message": "Undefined index: $",
    "status_code": 500
}
```

but if I save this file to csv and try to import all work like a charm. What is wrong with xslx format?

Comment: can u show me your code??

Comment: please, share with us a snippet of your code.

Answer (score 6):

Just putting my 2 cents....

Check that your excel headings are small letters - $row['SomeHeading'] = $row['someheading']

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. It's very simple but I can't found it on google for few hours. If you get this error just try to re-save excel file. It's some issue with encoding.